# ckEditor remove div tag from ul list

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I read some `html` from database and pass it to `ckeditor` the problem is `ckeditor` edit my `html` here is the data that came from Database

```
  
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Coffee</li>
            <li>Tea</li>
            <li>Milk</li>
            <div>I Am DiV</div>
        </ul> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

and here is the `ckEditor` source Shows

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head><meta charset='UTF - 8'><meta name='viewport' content='width = device - width, initial - scale = 1.0'>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>I Am DiV</div>
    
    <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is my config

```
    config.fullPage = true;
    config.allowedContent = true;
```

How can i disable `ckEditor` to change my `html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to disable some CKEditor validation

```
config.enterMode = 2; //disabled <p>
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR; // pressing the ENTER KEY input <br/>
config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P; //pressing the SHIFT + ENTER KEYS input <p>
config.autoParagraph = false; // stops automatic insertion of <p> on focus
```

also if you need valid more tags you can use

```
config.protectedSource.push(/<i[^>]*><\/i>/g); //disable i validation
```

but you should customize it.